# Fully dynamic SharePoint 2010 Forms (newform.aspx,Edit.aspx etc.) generation

Tags: 2010, custom-form, list-form

**What we want :**

A Form that display normal document library fields and in between show some **custom controls** e.g. Listbox,dropdowns,buttons.

**How it works :**

Custom controls hold associated task item data and on saving Form, task item data is updated resulting in workflow to proceed.

**Problems :**

1- We need to add this functionality in more than 60 document library/lists.

2- Custom control are completely dynamic based on workflow status e.g if "In approval required" then show button of Approve/reject etc.

How to generate such dynamic forms ??

Please help, Thanks in advance.

*Note: i was thinking to create a application page and pragmatically create forms on fly.*